# How to update the Table of Content for a office-js word addin DocCreated object?

Tags: office-js

In reference to: [#1200](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-reference/issues/1200)

[Word.DocumentCreated class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.documentcreated?view=word-js-preview)

I just used the save function and it works very well.

However, fields are not updated. For ex, I have a table of content that must be updated as I manipulated / created the word file.

How should I do this? Any help would be welcomed!

Thank you!

Wondering if the table of content is a [Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.field?view=word-js-preview) and so how to find and update it.

Answer (score 1):

I found it, see below this might help someone.

The Table of contents is actually a Field. Its 'type' property contains the type of field, 'TOC' is used for Table of contents. So first retrieve all Fields, then filter the type with TOC.There is a function which updates a field: updateResult

```
   const AllFields: Word.FieldCollection = reportDoc.body.fields;
    AllFields.load('type');
    await context.sync();

    //Filter out TOC fields and update
    const tocFields: Word.Field[] = AllFields.items.filter((field: Word.Field) => field.type === 'TOC');
    tocFields.forEach((field: Word.Field) => field.updateResult());
    await context.sync();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).